# Should I test for unsupported Django versions in PyPI published packages?

Tags: python, django, pypi

I have some packages on PyPI, some of which are actually used by others.

When I drop support for older Django versions, what is the best way to inform the user (apart from changelog/history file)?

EDIT: I know about using `install_requires` in `setup.py`, but this would install Django if someone installs my package. I think this is bad practice, a Django component should not install Django itself. Other package authors seem to agree with this (look at Django REST Framework), but not all (look at Django Debug Toolbar).

Should I explicitly make the app fail if Django version does not match? Can I put this elegantly in `setup.py` (without forcing a Django install)? Other solutions (preferably best practices)? Input welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your requirements in setup.py and requirements file.
Say, you are providing support for django versions greater than django 1.6.

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
     ...
     install_requires = [
          'django>1.6'
     ],
)
```

You should add `django>1.6` to your requirements file, too.

For further guidance, consult - [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I should add to my question that I agree with the practice that Django packages should not install Django for you (see Django REST framework and others as a good example). I have uprooted this answer and will clarify my question.